# PHP login Script Generate Session But Not Header() Move to Home page

Tags: php, mysql, session, authentication

PHP login Script Generate Session But Not Header() Move to Home page.

```
<?php
session_start();
$message="";
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {
    if(count($_POST)>0) {
        $username=$_POST["user_name"];
        $password=$_POST["password"];
        if(!empty($username) && !empty($password)){
            //include  connection file
            require_once "connection.php";
            $sql="SELECT * FROM `admin_users` WHERE `admin_user` LIKE  'username' AND `admin_pass`LIKE'$password'";
            $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
            $row=mysqli_fetch_row($result);
            if(is_array($row)) {
                $_SESSION["user_id"] = $row[0];
                $_SESSION["admin_name"] = $row[1];
                $_SESSION["type"]="admin_map";

                mysql_close($dbhandle);
            } else {
                $message = "Invalid Username or Password!";
            }
        }
        if(isset($_SESSION["user_id"]) &&  isset($_SESSION["admin_name"]) &&  isset($_SESSION["admin_name"])=="admin@map") {
            header("Location:user_dashboard.php");
        }
    }
    else{
        $message = "Fill All Fields!";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried `header("Location: /user_dashboard.php");` See http://stackoverflow.com/a/25241503/1604068

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all add spaces in your query.
And you are missing $ sign before username `$username`.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM `admin_users` WHERE `admin_user` LIKE '$username' AND `admin_pass` LIKE '$password'";
```

I don't know why are you using LIKE in Login form. This must be check with **= operator**. (**Just Suggestion**)

Main issue in your code is that you are using `mysqli_*` extension and using `mysql_close()` for closing database connection.

```
mysql_close($dbhandle);
```

This should be

```
mysqli_close($dbhandle);
```

but use connection close at the end of your PHP script not between.

Comment: I would also **strongly** recommend using `mysqli_real_escape_string()` because you're leaving this query wide open to SQL-injection attacks. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php#example-1905

Comment: @sevvlor yes u r right. Code open for SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

change

```
header("Location:user_dashboard.php");
```

to

```
echo "<script>window.locaion='user_dashboard.php'</script>"
```

or add `ob_start()`in first line of code

Comment: firstly there is a typo in the suggested javascript and secondly this is not a good idea