# HTML and nested if statements

Tags: php, if-statement, nested

I have simplified the code to the basics and I get the same error.

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php if ('b'=='b') {
        if ('a'=='a'):?> 
             <a href="index_login.php">New Page</a>  
        <?php endif; ?>
    }     
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have a `<?php endif; ?>` in the middle of you code. If you remove it, it would work better.

Comment: @this.lau_ Its the `?>` closing that line, its cuts off the rest of the script.

Comment: @this.lau_ That `endif` belongs to an `if`…!

Comment: It would appear that the if with the endif breaks the parameter association with netbeans. Or  I'm doing it wrong? If I take the code listed below, it shows the basic code works and the associations now also work. Hence the posting, I'm stuck.

Comment: If I replace the 3 lines with the below, it works. I would still like to know why the original code does not work. It will catch me out some time later.                                                                                      if ($_SESSION['Password'] == $_POST['Password']){
   header("Location: mem_page.php");      
exit;                        
}

Comment: How do post code in a comment ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {     
    if (!empty($_POST['LicenceNo']) && $_SESSION['MEMID'] == '')  {
        require ('sql_get_MNZID.php');                       
    }else { 
        if(isset($_SESSION['Password']) && isset($_POST['Password'])){                
            if ($_SESSION['Password'] == $_POST['Password']){
                echo '<a href="index_login.php">New Page</a>';    
            }  
        }
    }
}else{
    $_SESSION['MEMID'] = '';
    $_SESSION['Password'] = '';   
    $_SESSION['MemName'] = '';
}    
?>
```

**Modification:-**To redirect to another page then 
replace this

```
if ($_SESSION['Password'] == $_POST['Password']){
          echo '<a href="index_login.php">New Page</a>';    
}
```

with this

```
if ($_SESSION['Password'] == $_POST['Password']){
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">location.href = "index_login.php";</script>';  
}
```

It will work for you.

This works

```
if ($_SESSION['Password'] == $_POST['Password']){
    header("Location: mem_page.php");      
    exit;                        
}
```

Comment: Yes that works. That is what I had before I added in the href link. I now have an active URL link on my page.

Comment: your issue solved ?

Comment: No I cant get the bit to work to go to a new url if    -- if ($_SESSION['Password'] == $_POST['Password']) -- is true. Code as in my original posting.

Comment: `'<a href="index_login.php">New Page</a>'` is not printing or anything else you want?

Comment: I don't want it to print, I want to go to that page.

Comment: Try this modification.

Comment: That will work but I am trying to not use Javascript. The question I still have is, why the code does not work. As I said above, this type of coding will probably catch me out some other time so best I get is right now.

Comment: Your issue is solved or not?For your question you can check here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871942/how-to-redirect-to-another-page-using-php

Comment: Not yet. I have looked through the links but none answer my question. I should re-phrase the question to, how to escape from a nested PHP if set of statements.