# .htaccess error ( ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS )

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I installed a new plugin (BackWPup) on my wordpress installation.
Since then the website shows **"ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"**.

> The example.com page isn’t working
>
> mysite.com redirected you too many times.
>
> Try clearing your cookies.

Cannot access my admin dashboard anymore to deinstall the plugin.
**So I logged into the server and had a look at my `.htaccess` file to find any redirection loops. Anyone have any Ideas on how to fix this issue?**

my `.htaccess` file:

````
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]    
</IfModule>

php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
php_value post_max_size 128M
php_value memory_limit 256M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300
# END WordPress```
````

Comment: [The plugin itself may do the redirects.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871942/how-to-redirect-to-another-page-using-php) .htaccess *seems* not to be the reason for the redirects. [You may need to deactivate the plugin by hand.](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+disable+wordpress+plugins+without+admin+access) Make backups if you havent done so yet ...

Comment: I will try. Thank you for your answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

the .htaccess file wasn't the problem. The plugin itself was the problem. So wanted to delete it manually on the server. Couldn't delete it **but rename the folder of the plugin was enough**! Website and loging in to the dashboard is working again! Thank you!