# Redirecting html page to another page using php

Tags: php, html

I am having problems getting php to redirect after processing an email message. I've tried all of the solutions mentioned on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871942/how-to-redirect-to-another-page-using-php), as well as some involving javascript with no luck. Here are the relevant portions of my code:

```
function redirect($url) {
ob_start();
header('Location: '.$url);
ob_end_flush();
exit();
}

if ( isset($_REQUEST['sendemail']) ) {
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
header("X-Node: $hostname");
$from = $_REQUEST['from'];
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$toemail = "djsuson@gmail.com";
$subject = "Customer question";
$message = $_REQUEST['message'];

ob_start(); //start capturing output buffer because we want to change output to html

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->IsSMTP();
if ( strpos($hostname, 'cpnl') === FALSE ) //if not cPanel
    $mail->Host = 'relay-hosting.secureserver.net';
else
    $mail->Host = 'localhost';
$mail->SMTPAuth = false;

$mail->From = $from;
$mail->FromName = $name;
$mail->AddAddress($toemail);

$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body = $message;

$mailresult = $mail->Send();
$mailconversation = nl2br(htmlspecialchars(ob_get_clean()));
if ( !$mailresult ) {
    echo 'FAIL: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo . '<br />' . $mailconversation;
    redirect('http://otterlywoods.com/failure.html');
} else {
    echo $mailconversation;
    redirect('http://otterlywoods.com/success.html');
}
```

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: If you show PHP errors while coding or look at error log if you are on production site, you should see [headers already sent error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php). Headers must be sent before echo out any body message. You should re-design your process (read the link).

Comment: _"I am having problems"_ - isn't helpful in any way, it's pretty much goes without saying since you're posting a question here. Please always add what actually happens. Also do some proper debugging to narrow the issue down. Do you get any errors/warnings (check the web servers error log). Does anything in that code work? If yes, where exactly does it stop working?

Comment: @M.Eriksson: In response to your comment, the code is working fine, with the exception of not redirecting. I get the created email from the web page, no errors are generated that I can find, and I don't see any errors/warnings when I look at the logs made available by goDaddy. It just isn't executing the redirect after sending the email. I have tried to echo out information to try and debug this, but haven't gotten anything that I've found on the web page.

Comment: So far I have tried

- using the redirect() call as shown in the code above
- putting the header() call directly in the script where the redirect() call is
- creating a variable outside of the nested if statement, putting 'OK'/'FAIL' in the variable depending on what $mailresult contains, and redirecting at the end of the function immediately before the exit()
- placing a javascript redirect in the javascript that parses the form output when the send button is clicked
- using a variable to capture the request.statusText value to print out/trigger the redirect

None of these have worked

Comment: Remove the other headers. It makes no sense to have a content type when you're going to redirect the user away. You can also try to remove your `ob_*`-functions since I don't see the purpose of them in this case. And your code will call `ob_start()` twice, which could cause issues when flushing. Then you also need to remove your `echo`'s since you can't have _any_ output _at all_ before you call `header()`. Also disable SMTPDebug for PHPMailer (as that generates output as well if enabled.) Read the link @vee posted.

Comment: @M.Eriksson, I commented out the ob-* lines in the redirect function, the two header lines after the if ( isset($_REQUEST['sendemail']) ) {, the ob_start after elseif ( $_REQUEST['sendmethod'] == "smtp" ), and echo lines in the mailresult logic statement. It did not change the result. I still got the email but was not redirected off of the page.

Comment: When writing your code, I recommended to [display all errors (1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438060/showing-all-errors-and-warnings) , [(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display). If `SMTPDebug` is not set to off (`0`), when you call `send()` they should echo out the debug message and this body message is out before `header()` which is wrong (as I said before).

Comment: I did everything that @M.Eriksson said above and everything works fine. 1. remove `ob_*` functions inside `redirect()` function as it is no need. 2. Check your open and close `{...}` for `if` condition. It doesn't matched in the code above. 3. `$hostname` is come from no where it should showing undefined variable error. Set this variable or remove it. 4. Remove and `echo` before `header()`. That's all. And enable all errors as I said before.

Comment: I commented out all of the echo and header lines that are in area that I've changed. The mailing code is using a PHPMailer class that appears to set some others. The script that I got and modified from goDaddy also has some Javascript, which creates a table showing the results of the mail call. This is showing the redirect as part of the result. Is there any way of sharing the full code and/or (preferably) taking some of this private?